# Drawing multiple Shapes on the same Canvas when pressed a button

Tags: java, swing, drawing, awt, factory-pattern

I need to draw a square,line,circle when pressed the corespondent button. Also I need to do this using FactoryMethod design pattern.
I simply don't get how to draw on the same canvas, and because I have a class for every shape, how do i get the corresponding paint(Graphics g) method? 
This is what I have so far:

```
public interface Shape

{

          public void draw();

}
```

Square class

```
public class Square extends Canvas implements Shape
{
    Graphics g;

    Canvas c;

    public Canvas getCanvas()
    {
        return c;
    }
    public void setCanvas(Canvas c)
    {
        this.c=c;
    }
    @Override
    public void draw() 
    {
        g.drawRect(20, 30,100,100);

    }
    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        g.drawRect(20, 30,100,100);
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    }


}
```

Factory

```
public class ClassFactory extends Canvas{

    JButton patrat;
    Figura d;
    String nameButon;
    Graphics g;
    Canvas c;
    public Canvas getCanvas()
    {
        return c;
    }
    public void setCanvas(Canvas c)
    {
        this.c=c;
    }
    public ClassFactory()
    {
        super();
        this.setBounds(0,0,500,450);
        this.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        JButton square=new JButton("square");
        patrat.setBounds(510, 10, 80,25);

        JPanel panel=new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(null);
        panel.setBounds(0,0,600,500);
        panel.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        panel.add(this);
        this.addComponentListener(p);
        panel.add(square);

        JFrame f=new JFrame("Draw");
        f.setLayout(null);
        f.setBounds(50,50,700,600);
        f.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        f.setResizable(false);
        f.add(panel);

        f.show();
           }

    public Shape getFigure()
    {
        Shape d=null;
        if(nameButton.equals("square"))
        {
            d=new Square();
        }
        return d;

    }   
}
```

Comment: One thing that could help us is if you post the actual assignment text. What are they requiring that you specifically do? Sometimes they do in fact recommend that you do crazy stuff like draw in a Canvas that is displayed in a JFrame. And are they requiring that the `draw(...)` method accept no parameters? Please show us the actual requirements.

Comment: `setLayout(null);`  Java GUIs might have to work on a number of platforms, on different screen resolutions & using different PLAFs.  As such they are not conducive to exact placement of components.  To organize the components for a robust GUI, instead use layout managers, or combinations of them, along with layout padding & borders for white space.

Comment: @Ana his did you find solution for above question? can you update your question with answer, I would be glad if you help me to find out solution. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suggestions:

- The factory should not create a GUI, should not extend Canvas, or really extend anything, it should not create a JFrame or do anything of the sort. It should concern itself only with creating objects of Shape child classes. The GUI creation code should be elsewhere.
- Likely the factory's `getFigure(...)` method will be the one to produce this. It should likely accept a parameter, perhaps a String or an enum, that tells it what sub-class of Shape to produce.
- Shape's draw method should likely accept a Graphics parameter so that its children can use it to draw with.
- You shouldn't mix AWT components (i.e., Canvas) and Swing components together unnecessarily. Instead, just draw in a JPanel's `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method, not in a Canvas's `paint(Graphics g)` method.
- In that JPanel have a Shape variable that is not initialized, perhaps called shape.
- Inside of `paintComponent(...)` check if shape is null. If not, draw it by calling `shape.draw(g)`.
- In your JButton ActionListeners, have the Factory create a Shape child class object and assign it to the shape variable
- Then call `repaint()` on the JPanel that does the drawing.